# Adding video background for mobile on wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Wonder if you can help. I've been trying to add background mp4 to a WordPress site I am developing for a client. I've explained that its a bad idea due to data usage but he is insistent.

When I added the mp4, I quickly understood that by default this action isn't supported. However, there must be a work around. I have read the posts here and googled extensively.

so far, what I've come up with is using @media to resolve.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.header-video {
    display: block !important;
}
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work either. Other than creating a gif is there any other way?

Additional HTML Code: -- I am interested in the video loop tag with the MP4 in

```html
<div id="main-content">


   
    <article id="post-54" class="post-54 page type-page status-publish hentry">

    
     <div class="entry-content">
     <div id="et-boc" class="et-boc">
   
   <div class="et_builder_inner_content et_pb_gutters3"><div class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_0 header-video et_pb_section_video et_pb_preload et_pb_with_background et_section_regular">
    
    
    <span class="et_pb_section_video_bg">
     
   <video loop="loop" autoplay playsinline muted >
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://fortuna-x.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Deep-Network-Green-Blue.mp4" />
    
   </video>
    </span>
    
     <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_0">
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_3 et_pb_column_0    et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et_pb_column_empty">
    
    
    
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_column --><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_2_3 et_pb_column_1    et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child et_pb_column_empty">
    
    
    
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->
    
    
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_row --><div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_1 et_pb_equal_columns et_pb_gutters150">
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_3 et_pb_column_2    et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
```

Comment: can you provide more code (HTML)?

Comment: Lots of mobile browsers will only allow a video to play if it's triggered by a user action (`autoplay` and triggering play with JS are blocked) making a video background generally unreliable on mobile. You might just have to explain the technical limitations to your client, or at least make sure you provide a nice fallback.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Can you tell us which WordPress theme and page builder you are using ?

Comment: you want for tablet or ipad or android ?

Comment: additional HTML code added at request. I am using Divi theme 3.1.1 - I can build directly from the theme itself. Clever really! :)

Comment: Charan, I'd prefer to support all devices, but android would be the primary choice. I have seen a website that has done it with .js, but it's not quite the same as the effect I am after. thanks for the help though, it is muchly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As of April, 2018. [Chrome Autoplay policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) has changed. In order to autoplay your videos on the site, you're media engagement score needs to be high. Examples from the docs.

> Example 1: Every time a user visits VideoSubscriptionSite.com on their
>   laptop they watch a TV show or a movie. As their media engagement
>   score is high, autoplay is allowed.
>
> Example 2: GlobalNewsSite.com has both text and video content. Most
>   users go to the site for text content and watch videos only
>   occasionally. Users' media engagement score is low, so autoplay
>   wouldn't be allowed if a user navigates directly from a social media
>   page or search.
>
> Example 3: LocalNewsSite.com has both text and video content. Most
>   people enter the site through the homepage and then click on the news
>   articles. Autoplay on the news article pages would be allowed because
>   of user interaction with the domain. However, care should be taken to
>   make sure users aren't surprised by autoplaying content.
>
> Example 4: MyMovieReviewBlog.com embeds an iframe with a movie trailer
>   to go along with their review. The user interacted with the domain to
>   get to the specific blog, so autoplay is allowed. However, the blog
>   needs to explicitly delegate that privilege to the iframe in order for
>   the content to autoplay.

To check weather you're media score is high enough you can check it like this.

```
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
  promise.then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started!
  }).catch(error => {
    // Autoplay was prevented.
    // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.
  });
}
```

So, if you get an error, you can show the play button. The user would then need to click on it to start the video.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Gregor. The mp4 I am trying to play is part of the design and not content. it auto-plays just fine on pc. The restriction is based on mobile phones not playing background media to save data.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/video-settings-twenty-seventeen-theme/
After creating children them it’s enough to add these code lines to the file functions.php:

```
/*
* Change the minimum screen size to use the video header
*/
function twentyseventeenchild_video_size( $settings ) {
$settings[‘minWidth’] = 100;
$settings[‘minHeight’] = 100;
return $settings;
}
add_filter( ‘header_video_settings’, ‘twentyseventeenchild_video_size’ );
```

it works!

Answer (score 0):

Best way is u can use any wordpress plugin for adding video background for mobile...
like https://envato.com/blog/plugins-video-backgrounds/

Comment: I already have the background in place - problem is it doesn't play on mobile. I am looking for a work around :)

Comment: it is auto play background video... ??

Comment: if the video is auto play video then u need to look the following link... https://www.aerserv.com/blog/why-does-video-autoplay-on-mobile-devices-not-work/#

Comment: Hi Shahid - Thank you, but I don't need an addon, all of the add-ons are the same, they don't natively support mobile device. They all fall back to a background image when the video doesn't auto play.

Comment: Hi Shahid  - I missed your second link, sorry. thank you for the info.